# Неиспользуемые хранимые процедуры и функции в пакете

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

За огромный промежуток времени в конкретном пакете хранимых процедур собралось куча мусорных процедур и функций, мы не можем вероятно сказать что из этого используется и давно не вызывалось.

Существуют ли какие методы, которые позволяют проанализировать, как давно вызывалась конкретная процедура/функция в пакете?

Comment: по вашему логу, если процедуры что-то туда пишут.  ну или никак :)